# How to replace certain character with a defined character for it in a string using php?

Tags: php, html

I have a question that can I replace a certain character like `#` with `&#35;` in a string.
I have all the character checkers and their replacer in an array. Like this--

```
$string_check = array(
                      "#" => "&#35;",
                      .... and so on (list is too big)
                     );
```

So how can I do this thing. Please help me out. I only have 20 days of experience with php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can feed your translation table right into [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/strtr):

```
$table = array(
    '#' => '...',
);
$result = strtr($source, $table);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) does exactly that and it also accepts arrays as replacement maps:

```
$string_check = array(
    "#" => "&#35;"
);

$result = str_replace (array_keys($string_check), array_values($string_check), $original);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = array('hello','foo');
$replace = array('world','bar');

$text = 'hello foo';
$result = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
// $result will be 'world bar'
```

but in your case it looks like some kind of encoding, have you tried the `htmlspecialchars`?